# No sound under Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sound, 12.10

I've followed this :

[Howto - Resolve no sound problem on Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04 and Older](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/)

In addition, I've disabled auto-mute in alsamixer.  If I play a sound under VLC, I can see in pavu, that there's something playing - that the volume is registered - yet I hear nothing.

I recall my sound working prior to about a week ago, but it seems to have abruptly stopped on its own.

Comment: After doing a lot of experimenting today, I think this is related to the latest kernels, as on -18 and had no nvidia driver but had sound. As soon as I manually installed the headers and manually installed nvidia-current, I now have no sound.  Any ideas on how to restore?

Comment: You can try removing NVidia drivers and re-checking the results.

Comment: I've done that, and have sound then.  Coincidentally, I also loaded Linux Mint 14 RC and had the same experience out of the box.

Comment: **Update :** Now I lost my sound! Fiddled with alsamixer as per link. Now only one earphone slot works. No sound from speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the sound driver has a very good chance of solving your problem:

```
sudo /sbin/alsa force-reload
```